# magit with tramp is not working with git correctly

Tags: magit, tramp

I installed magit. I added the following lines to my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'tramp)
(push "/path/to/git/directory/" tramp-remote-path)
```

And when I am in tramp I run `M-x magit-version` here is the output:

```
Magit 20170808.1712, Git (unknown), Emacs 25.2.1, darwin
```

So despite being pointed at the right git it definitely isn't finding it. I checked `magit-git-executable` and it is "git" and the correct path is at the start of `tramp-remote-path`.

Time for option #2. I changed my `.emacs`, removing the previous two lines and adding this:

```
(setq magit-git-executable "/path/to/git/directory/git")
```

Now I can get magit to show the correct git version, I can open `magit-status`. But now I get

```
"Error in post-command-hook (magit-auto-revert-mode-check-buffers): (file-error "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "/path/to/git/directory/git")
```

no matter what I do. I cannot switch buffers, I cannot close buffers, I cannot exit. I am forced to do a force quit from the OS.

Questions:

- Why doesn't `tramp-remote-path` work at all?
- Why does setting `magit-git-executable` screw things up so bad I can't even exit Emacs normally?
- Why is it so hard to get Emacs, git, tramp and magit to play nice together?
- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No. Not literally. The path doesn't matter other than to note that the path I used in tramp-remote-path was the same path (with "git" appended) that I used with magit-git-executable.

Comment: OP, TRAMP can cache stale path information. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/how-can-i-diagnose-which-git-magit-is-running.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that stackexchange is the best medium to solve your problem. It needs debugging. I recommend you send your problem to both the Tramp mailing list `tramp-devel@gnu.org` and the Magit mailing list (don't know the address) as one message.

Answering your questions:

- Why doesn't `tramp-remote-path` work at all?

  This needs debugging. Set `tramp-verbose` to 6, rerun your test, and show the resulting Tramp debug buffer (not here, at the Tramp mailing list).
- Why does setting `magit-git-executable` screw things up so bad I can't even exit Emacs normally?

  Don't know, I'm not using Magit.
- Why is it so hard to get Emacs, git, tramp and magit to play nice together?

  Well, Tramp and Magit are different packages. You must bring us together, as you have done with your question.
- What am I doing wrong?

  Let's see ...

Michael Albinus, Tramp maintainer

Comment: Okay. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll send off some e-mails per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed this issue on my own machine with:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/path/to/git/on/remote/machine")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
```