# How can I diagnose which `git` magit is running?

Tags: magit, tramp

I'm trying to use Magit with TRAMP.  The remote host has multiple git versions, necessitating

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/usr/sup/bin")
```

in my `.emacs`.  However, when I run `magit-status` in a TRAMP buffer, I get this error message in `*Messages*`:

```
magit-insert-head-branch-header: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

And it is accompanied by this message in `*Warnings*`:

```
Error (magit): Magit requires Git >= 2.0.0, but on /ssh:nr@homework: the version is 1.8.3.

If multiple Git versions are installed on the host, then the
problem might be that TRAMP uses the wrong executable.

First check the value of `magit-git-executable'.  Its value is
used when running git locally as well as when running it on a
remote host.  The default value is "git", except on Windows
where an absolute path is used for performance reasons.

If the value already is just "git" but TRAMP never-the-less
doesn't use the correct executable, then consult the info node
`(tramp)Remote programs'.
```

Information about the context:

- The value of `magit-git-executable` is `"git"`.
- The value of `tramp-remote-path` is `("/usr/sup/bin" tramp-default-remote-path "/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/local/bin" "/local/freeware/bin" "/local/gnu/bin" "/usr/freeware/bin" "/usr/pkg/bin" "/usr/contrib/bin" "/opt/bin" "/opt/sbin" "/opt/local/bin")`.
- On the remote host, there is a `/usr/sup/bin/git` with version 2.19.1.

My question: how I can figure out the absolute pathname of the `git` that Magit is running on the remote host?

Possibly relevant question: [magit with tramp is not working with git correctly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35055/magit-with-tramp-is-not-working-with-git-correctly)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it may give more information: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, try it again and look at the backtrace (or add it to the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the value already is just "git" but TRAMP never-the-less
>   doesn't use the correct executable, then consult the info node
>   `(tramp)Remote programs'.

Did you do that?  It says:

> When remote search paths are changed, local TRAMP caches must be
>   recomputed.  To force TRAMP to recompute afresh, exit Emacs, remove the
>   persistent file (*note Connection caching::), and restart Emacs.

And you would probably use:

> ## 6.6 Cleanup remote connections
>
> TRAMP provides several ways to flush remote connections.
>
> -- Command: tramp-cleanup-connection vec
>        This command flushes all connection related objects.  ‘vec’ is the
>        internal representation of a remote connection.  When called
>        interactively, this command lists active remote connections in the
>        minibuffer.  Each connection is of the format ‘/method:user@host:’.
>        Flushing remote connections also cleans the password cache (*note
>        Password handling::), file cache, connection cache (*note
>        Connection caching::), and connection buffers.
>
> -- Command: tramp-cleanup-this-connection
>        Flushes only the current buffer’s remote connection objects, the
>        same as in ‘tramp-cleanup-connection’.
>
> -- Command: tramp-cleanup-all-connections
>        Flushes all active remote connection objects, the same as in
>        ‘tramp-cleanup-connection’.
>
> -- Command: tramp-cleanup-all-buffers
>        Just as for ‘tramp-cleanup-all-connections’, all remote connections
>        are cleaned up in addition to killing buffers related to that
>        remote connection.

Comment: Consulted the info page, but missed the part about the cache.  Problem solved!  Thanks kindly.

Comment: With a local repository, `(tramp-cleanup-all-connections)` and  `(tramp-cleanup-all-buffers)` were sufficient to convince magit to stop trying to connect remotely. Thanks for the time-saving pointers.

Comment: Fyi, the pair of cleanup-all commands do save you from re-opening emacs and solved my identical issue, but the latter still closes all tramp-related buffers, which somewhat defeats the purpose of not simply restarting emacs in it's entirety.

Comment: Are you sure `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` wasn't sufficient on its own?  (Also if you *are* using `tramp-cleanup-all-buffers` then per the documentation you wouldn't need to run `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` first.)

Comment: `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` was not enough. Having buffers still triggers `tramp-signal-hook-function: Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens repeatedly, try
    ‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’` when running `M-x magit`, it went away after `tramp-cleanup-all-buffers`