# Load right version of Git while connecting to remote

Tags: magit, tramp, git, remote

I am currently working on a remote using Lmod for handling modules. I want to use Magit with the repositories on this remote, but the default system version of Git is 1.x.
However, Git 2.18 is available on the cluster as a module (accessible at `/software/git-2.18/bin/git`), which I already called in my `.bashrc` through `module add git-2.18`.

When Magit connects to the remote through Tramp, though, it still calls Git 1.x, resulting in

```
Error (magit): Magit requires Git >= 2.2.0, but on /ssh:myremote: the version is 1.x.x.
If multiple Git versions are installed on the host, then the
problem might be that TRAMP uses the wrong executable.
First check the value of `magit-git-executable'.  Its value is
used when running git locally as well as when running it on a
remote host.  The default value is "git", except on Windows
where an absolute path is used for performance reasons.
If the value already is just "git" but TRAMP never-the-less
doesn't use the correct executable, then consult the info node
`(tramp)Remote programs'.
```

(The default value was Git already)

I currently fixed this temporarily by setting the custom variable `magit-remote-git-executable` to `"/software/git-2.18/bin/git"`, but it makes it impossible to work on other remotes without modifying the variable manually each time.

Would you have any thoughts on how to fix this on either end?

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/how-can-i-diagnose-which-git-magit-is-running?newreg=895f0c9d3ddb43e79041136a190b58a4) helped me solve the issue.

Comment: This [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/67975/load-right-version-of-git-while-connecting-to-remote#autocomment116962) helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Connection Variables` to conditionally set `magit-remote-git-executable` on the hosts where you want that?

You could alternatively try setting `tramp-remote-path` such that your preferred location (if it exists) will be examined first when looking for `git`; but you may get better performance with `magit-remote-git-executable` set explicitly, so I'd try that first.

Comment: So something like 
`(connection-local-set-profile-variables 'myremote-config
        '((shell-file-name . "/bin/bash")
          (shell-command-switch . "-c module add git-2.18")))
     (connection-local-set-profiles
        '(:application tramp :machine "myremote") 'myremote-config)`

right?

Comment: Tested it as above but it did not work

Comment: I've no clue about the "module" command.  My suggestion was to set `magit-remote-git-executable`.

Comment: Oh I think I got what you mean, sorry I got bamboozled by the docs. More like this?  `(connection-local-set-profile-variables 'myremote-config
'((shell-file-name . "/bin/bash")
(magit-remote-git-executable . "/software/git-2.18/bin/git")))
(connection-local-set-profiles 
'(:application tramp :machine "myremote") 'myremote-config)`

Comment: That's the idea.  Seems like it doesn't affect dired buffers, but I can see that it works for file-visiting buffers.

Comment: It still doesn't work with the files on my end, unfortunately. I tried setting up `:machine` with both the absolute path and my local SSH alias, but I keep getting `magit-insert-head-branch-header: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

Comment: Hmm.  It was working for me insofar as `magit-remote-git-executable` was set to the specified path in a file-visiting buffer, but my idea may be flawed in that magit buffers are not visiting a file, and perhaps in those buffers it is winding up being set to `nil`.  Causing `hack-connection-local-variables` to be called in `magit-mode-hook` *might* work around that, but I can't test this right now.

Comment: I tried to add it; unfortunately, the result is the same. A kind stranger on the internet suggested to try with a minor mode, but I am not sure on how would that differ from what we're doing here.

Comment: So it sounds like my first idea isn't going to do the trick, but I think my other suggestion should still work -- globally set `tramp-remote-path` with the (potential) bin dir for a newer git being first in the list.  I had been aiming to set `magit-remote-git-executable` to avoid a path lookup, but at this point I'd definitely suggest seeing how you fare with the path-based approach, as it's simpler, and it might be totally fine.

Comment: If you do want to set `magit-remote-git-executable` then my best suggestion it this point is to have custom code checking `default-directory` and setting the executable accordingly.  You could run that in `after-change-major-mode-hook`.